# How do I copy dependencies to output directory with `maven package`

Tags: java, maven, lwjgl

I have a project which uses LWJGL, and I would like to copy the required jars and related natives to the output directory of the generated jar. I would not like to inject the dependencies into the final jar itself.

I can run `mvn package` and `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`, both of which work great.

My attempts to run the goal "copy-dependencies" is by adding an execution to the "maven-dependency-plugin" as follows:

```xml
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>
        ${project.build.directory}/libs
      </outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

and again, as referenced by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23986765/2082195), with the same result: packaging completes, creating a jar, but no dependencies beside it. no logging that `prepare-package` is occurring, or the `maven-dependency-plugin` is being run at all.

I've also tried binding to other phases, such as `package`, `validate`, `test`, and none of them will cause an execution to occur. This is the only execution in my `pom.xml`. I have only a handful of plugins:

```
maven-clean-plugin
maven-resources-plugin
maven-compiler-plugin
maven-jar-plugin (with a config declaring its manifest, shown below)
maven-install-plugin
maven-dependency-plugin
```

Aforementioned config:

```xml
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
      <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
      <mainClass>
        xyz.valnet.hadean.HadeanGame
      </mainClass>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
</configuration>
```

I additionally have 3 profiles, for selecting which LWJGL natives to use by setting the property `lwjgl-natives` and that being used in the dependencies.

My question is mainly: what things could cause this execution to not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plugins listed under `<pluginManagement>` will only get executed by projects in child directories which have their own `pom.xml`

plugins for execution in the current project should be listed without `<pluginManagement>`

to fix remove pluginManagement, or re-organize your plugins to correctly reflect which plugins should be run and which should be used for child projects.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    [...]
  </plugins>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      [...]
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```